# How to fix run-time error 52 in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, vba

I am experiencing run-time error 52: bad filename or number in excel 2016. However, I have no idea what is wrong with my code. Do you know what could be the problem?

[image]

As requested by Tim, I ran ? Global_FilePath in the Immediate Window:

```
  ? Global_FilePath
  C:\Users\AlwatchSite04\Desktop\db
  \barcodes\ASCRA
```

Comment: Try `? Global_FilePath` in the Immediate pane

Comment: Tim, I have added the output for "? Global_FilePath" to the post. Please see whether you can identify the problem with my code. I don't have this problem with excel 2007 or 2010.

Comment: It looks code_split(2) has an end of line character at the end of the string. Remove this character and it should work fine

Comment: Thanks! I added "Global_FilePath = Replace(code_split(2), vbCrLf, "") & "\barcodes\" & Input_Barcode" and it works.